# when use DLL in c++?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, dll

For the last 3 weeks I've been trying to create a code generator and my boss told me to put into a plugin DLL so we can call it next time when we want to reuse it !

So I searched the web for a Dll meaning but it still kind of vague , so if you have a better simple definition or a clear idea about DLL in C++ for beginners please enlighten me.

Another thing : I noticed that some uses QT to create plugin , so what's in QT that give us the possibility to do that that we can't find in any other IDE ?

PS: I've never used QT!

Comment: "it's still kind of vague"... but so is your question. What is it you didn't understand? We could give you a definition but it won't be clearer than what's on Wikipedia and other sites. You need to make your question clearer (and perhaps not so broad in scope).

Comment: what is a dll of c++ code ? how is it represented ? why do i need to create a dll for ? how could it be reused in a c++ code ? what options have QT for creating DLL in c++ ? etc

Comment: I hope your boss understands that a) reusing your code is possible without building a DLL and b) the task he's given you is beyond your current capabilities (so he better knows how to handle the situation of you not being able to perform the task).

Comment: I'm an intern and I'm supposed to learn !

Answer (score 2):

DLL-Dynamic Link Library is classes, methods and procedures packaged up into a compiled file to be used in conjunction with other programs. Its similar to an executable .exe file except you don't need a main method.